# Web video timecode seek

Tags: video, encoding, youtube, ffmpeg, video-streaming

On Youtube, you can seek to a particular video time, this is usually accurate to within one second.

I am trying to set up something similar (`JWPlayer`) has a plugin to allow seeking to a particular time), however it is usually about ten seconds off. Does this have to do with the spacing of keyframes, or how would I accomplish a better accuracy, like that done by YouTube? What encoding parameter do I need to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with the keyframes answer and I'm posting this because I couldn't fit it in a comment. 
Generally it's pointless to seek to a point between keyframes as video encoding on the whole is done on an additive basis post-keyframe. that is to say, it only adds the relevant frame data since the last keyframe reset (keyframes are full res pixel data for a frame, then other frames are just additions on top of it). This is why seeking gets rounded to the nearest keyframe.  Adding more keyframes will improve seeking accuracy but will increase the filesize.

This will change in the next year or two due to proposals to use the massive advances in FFT this year in video streaming technology.

Comment: thanks. Could you please provide a link to some information on the recent FFT enhancements/improvements?

Comment: yep have a look here: http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2012/faster-fourier-transforms-0118.html most image processing is done on a raster basis alone however this is changing towards frequency based approximation. its a short while off but the new developments this year in fft mean that frequency transformations can be done upto 10+ times faster which will be huge in regard to video codecs and the way they work

Answer (score 0):

Specify keyframes to be once every second (or every other second). Note that this will have an increase in the file size.